# I want to remove the string /auth, but when I try to do so , React shows a message that there is a memory leak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

```
export const API_BASE_URL = env.API_ENDPOINT_URL
export const APP_PREFIX_PATH = '/auth';
export const AUTH_PREFIX_PATH = '/app';
export const REDIRECT_URL_KEY = 'redirect'
export const AUTHENTICATED_ENTRY = `${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/dashboards/default`;
export const UNAUTHENTICATED_ENTRY = '/'
```

I am trying to remove /auth from my variable string, but when I make it empty, React throws a warning
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9uTz.png)

I want to remove /auth string, but it gives me lots of warning and application is getting crashed, need some help regarding this.

Comment: The error message is clear, try to debug it.

Comment: Share a component code which is calling useEffect, So we can look into it.